# Probability given two symptoms calculate probability of disease

Tags: probability, bayesian, bayes-theorem

I'm a little bit lost with probability and using Bayes theorem in practise.
Here's and exercise, I'm trying to figure out if I'm going in the right direction and if I read the exercise correctly (if i'm calculating the right thing)

Calculate the probability of a person having a disease D given that they are
showing both symptoms S1 and S2 shown on bayes network

[image: Bayes network graph]

Given values:

```
P(D) = 0.005
P(S1|D) = 0.4
P(S1|-D) = 0.02
P(S2|D) = 0.5
P(S2|-D) = 0.06
```

my interpretation of the excercise - `P(D|S1,S2)`

```
P(D|S1, S2) = 
P(S1,S2|D).P(D)/P(S1,S2) =
```

Now I'm calculating needed variables

```
P(-D) = 1-0.005 = 0.995
P(S1) = P(S1|D).P(D) + P(S1|-D).P(-D) = 0.4*0.005+0.02*0.995= 0.02189
P(S2) = P(S2|D).P(D) + P(S2|-D).P(-D) = 0.5*0.005+0.06*0.995=0.0621875
P(S1,S2) = 0.02189 * 0.0621875 = 0.001361284375
P(S1,S2|D) = P(S1|D) * P(S2|D) = 0.4*0.5 = 0.2
```

and now finally

```
P(S1,S2|D).P(D)/P(S1,S2) =
0.2*0.005/0.001361284375=
0.7346003659228073
```

Does any of this make sense?

Comment: No.  It is clearly not true that, unconditioned, $S_1,S_2$ are independent.  Seeing the first symptom is evidence for having the disease which clearly changes your estimate of the probability of seeing $S_2$.

Comment: I'd say, however, that it was fair to assume that, conditioned either on having or not having the disease, $S_1,S_2$ are independent.  If you don't assume something along those lines, then you really can't do the problem.

Comment: @lulu: I think the diagram is supposed to be a shorthand way of saying that the symptoms are conditionally independent conditioned on having the disease or conditioned on not having the disease

Comment: @Henry  The post was edited considerably after my comment...I was addressing the computation of $P(S_1,S_2)$.  The OP assumed independence and computed that as $P(S_1)\times P(S_2)$ but, as I say, they really can't be independent (unless conditioned).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, given that the diagram suggests conditional independence for the symptoms, you have

$$P(S_1,S_2 \mid D) = P(S_1 \mid D) \,P(S_2 \mid D)$$ so 
$$P(S_1,S_2, D) =  P(S_1 \mid D) \,P(S_2 \mid D) \, P(D)$$ and similarly 
$$P(S_1,S_2, \lnot D) =  P(S_1 \mid \lnot D) \,P(S_2 \mid\lnot D) \, P(\lnot D)$$ giving
$$P(S_1,S_2) = P(S_1,S_2, D) + P(S_1,S_2, \lnot D)$$ so 
$$P(D \mid S_1,S_2) =  \dfrac{P(S_1,S_2, D)}{P(S_1,S_2)} = \dfrac{P(S_1 \mid D) \,P(S_2 \mid D) \, P(D)}{P(S_1 \mid D) \,P(S_2 \mid D) \, P(D) + P(S_1 \mid \lnot D) \,P(S_2 \mid\lnot D) \, P(\lnot D)}$$